# Dynamic allocation or automatic recommended for subsystem creation?

Tags: c++, performance, heap-memory, stack-memory

I am a hobbyist C++ programmer and currently working on a game (using Ogre3D) and I have a question regarding the memory allocation for my main classes.

I have read a lot on memory allocation, allocating automatically on the stack and dynamically on the heap, and their differences (performance, limited stack size). Still I am not sure what to use for my main class (Application) and some other 'factory' classes (created by a single instance of the Application class), which will all have a single instance existing throughout the entire execution.

Below is a simplified snippet of the layout:

```
int main() 
{
    // like this (automatic)
    Application app;
    app.create();    // initializing
    app.run();       // runs the game-loop

    // or like this (dynamic)
    Application* app;
    app = new Application();
    app->create();
    app->run();

    return(0);       // only reached after exiting game
}



class Application
{
public:
    Application();   // ctor
    ~Application();  // dtor

    // like this, using 'new' in ctor and 'delete' in dtor (dynamic)
    SceneManager* sceneManager_;   // a factory for handling scene objects
    DebugManager* debugManager_;   // a factory for handling debugging objects

    // or like this (automatic)
    SceneManager sceneManager_;
    DebugManager debugManager_;
};
```

Is it better to allocate memory on the stack or on the heap (both for the Application class and the factory classes)? And by what arguments?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always prefer automatic allocation over dynamic allocation. And when you need dynamic allocation, make sure its lifetime is managed by automatically allocated resource wrappers, like smart pointers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That raises some more questions for me though. Won't I risk reaching the stack limits by automatic allocating these 'long-existing' main classes, since this stack space will be freed only after exiting the game? Moreover, object creation and deletion is done straightforward (by creation and deletion of the Application class), making memory leaking undoubtedly. Performance drops by dynamic allocation are of minor importance, because these objects are created only once at startup (loading screen). Following these arguments dynamic allocation is preferred, right?

Comment: @Bash: No, because nothing in your argument is founded on anything empirical. What evidence do you have you're doing to run out of stack space? Just put it on the stack like normal, and if stack space becomes a concern (i.e. crashes, which it very likely never will) *then* dynamically allocate it. Correctness is your primary concern, not trying to fix imaginary problems that haven't even manifested themselves yet.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer! I will stick to this explanation then. It is however a bit confusing, seeing different opinions on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation I think it all comes down to size.

You don't want to waste stack space, so either use dynamic allocation with `new` or put `Application` as a global variable outside `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the question is rather more complicated, but in general you can't avoid allocating on the heap.  For example, your `new` operation is allocating your `Application` object on the heap -- `new` allocates memory dynamically at run time, where the allocation of `auto` memory is *determined* at compile time.  (It's actually *allocated* at run time, of course -- but it's allocated as the startup code creates the stack for `main` according to the compiled-in allocations.)

Now, why would you *want* to avoid allocating on the heap?  It might be because of limited heap sizes, but with modern machines that's rarely a problem, even in hand-held devices.  Stack space might well be limited, however.  So that argues for heap.

Of course, `auto` memory doesn't "leak" -- but memory allocated in the main (or in file scope, although that's static) doesn't get freed, so one could almost claim it "automatically" leaked.

I think the essential question here is really "why *wouldn't* you allocate on the heap?"  The main reason is usually to avoid memory leaks, but care in using `new/delete` can protect you from that -- and given the ubiquity of dynamic allocation in libraries and such, you can't stop thinking about good memory hygiene even if you contrive to avoid dynamic allocation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The book of "Game Engine Architecture" by Jason Gregory suggests however the following rule of thumb: "keep heap allocations to a minimum...", as say many people. Why would I want to 'violate' that rule here?

Comment: Kind of depends on what's defined as "minimum". But think about what you lose by avoiding dynamic allocation: thinks like dynamic data structures that adapt to the workload, or the capability of using more memory in systems that have it. If they mean "use dynamic allocation when it's useful, but don't randomly allocate things dynamically because you can", then sure.